# Gradient paint issue in Chrome for Android on device with 512mb memory

Tags: html, css, cordova, android-webview, linear-gradients

I have Cordova app (used crosswalk-webview), it's contains several views and some views have lists with scrolling. Each row in this lists have gradient on row end for smoothly text hiding. And problem is:

[image: Gradient paint issue]

I have this markup and styles.

HTML:

```html
<div class="view-block list-block" style="padding-top: 0px;"> 
    <div class="view-block view-list">
        <div>
            <div class="row-wrapper status-row " style="touch-action: manipulation; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <div class="middle-container"> 
                    <span class="name"><i class="icon-status icon-status-ok"></i> Звонящий Для Тестов</span><br> 
                </div>
            </div>
            :after
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="row-wrapper status-row " style="touch-action: manipulation; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <div class="middle-container"> 
                    <span class="name"><i class="icon-status icon-status-off"></i> Емец Владимир Александрович</span><br>  
                    <span class="sub-name">Программист</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            :after
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```html
.view-main .list-block {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.view-block {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.view-main .view-list {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 0; /* For stack context using when paint */
}

.view-list > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.view-list > div .row-wrapper {
    height: 3em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.view-list > div .row-wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3em;
    width: 10%;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), to(#ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

If I disable `overflow-y` on `.view-main .view-list` gradient will paint **normally**, but scrolling on this element disabled.

Gradient paint normally if emulator have 1024mb memory or have Android version >= 5.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Chromium TRIM project, [topic](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/project-trim/7Ti1zJwvH8I) in Google Groups.

Solution for me - use `--disable-low-end-device-mod` for crosswalk-webview.